# How can I send data from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my cshtml code. This code prints selected data from select list into textbox.

```
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>CC</label></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="name" id="myInput_@item.id" value="" @(item.SelectedSpecs.Count > 0 ? "disabled" : "") /></td>
                        </tr>
                        @{
                            int selectid = item.id;
                        }
                        <tr>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="mySelect_@selectid" onchange="selectToInput(this)">
                                    <option value="">Kişi Seçiniz...</option>
                                    @foreach (var x in item.kullaniciIsimleri)
                                    {
                                        string value1 = x;
                                        <option value="@value1">@x</option>
                                    }
                                    <option value="TECTURA">TECTURA</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

This is my javascript code that allows me to do this.

```
        <script>
            function selectToInput(elem) {
                var selectValue = elem.value;
                var inputId = elem.id.replace("mySelect", "myInput");
                document.getElementById(inputId).value = selectValue;
        </script>
```

Here, on the same html page, I send some values ​​to the post method in my controller by pressing the "ask a question" button.

```
                    <div class="cord-footer">
                        <hr />
                        <form id="@item.id+formdata" action="@Url.Action("Ask_Question", "Question")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ItemId" value="@item.id" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="@Model.ProjectId" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="itemspecs" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="isinit" value="@item.SelectedSpecs.Count" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="questiontype" value="0" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="sendertype" value="0" />

                                <label>Ask Question</label>
                                <textarea name="Message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <input type="file" name="FileContent" class="form-control" />
                            <br />
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <input type="submit" data-type="askquestion" class="btn btn-kreon" value="Ask Question" />
                                <label class="pull-left" data-type="collapseQuestions">Conversation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

And this is my controller method.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Ask_Question(Zenon_data_PeraPortalPeraItemProItemQues question, HttpPostedFileBase FileContent, int pid, string itemspecs, int isinit, int questiontype, string CC,int sendertype, string formElement)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(question.Message))
                return RedirectToAction("ListQuestionList", "Question", new { pid = pid });

           
            var project = _db.Zenon_data_PeraPortalPeraItemProject.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == pid);
            var item = _db.Zenon_data_PeraPortalPeraItemProjectItem.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == question.ItemId);

            if (isinit == 0)
            {
                var sales = questiontype % 2 == 0;
                var tech = questiontype % 2 == 1;
                Init_QuestionItem(question.ItemId, itemspecs);
                item.is_Sales = Convert.ToByte(sales);
                item.is_Tech = Convert.ToByte(tech);
                
            }
            question.Date = DateTime.Now;
            question.Sender = User.User_ID;
            question.File = SaveFile(FileContent, pid, project.Name);
           
            question.Type = "";
           
            _db.Zenon_data_PeraPortalPeraItemProItemQues.Add(question);

            _db.SaveChanges();
            if(sendertype==0)
            return RedirectToAction("ListQuestionList", "Question", new { pid = pid });
            else if (sendertype == 1 && item.is_Tech == 1)
                return RedirectToAction("TechQuestionList", "Question", new { pid = pid });
            else if (sendertype == 1 && item.is_Sales == 1)
                return RedirectToAction("SaleQuestionList", "Question", new { pid = pid });
            else
            return RedirectToAction("ListQuestionList", "Question", new { pid = pid });
        }
```

My problem is that; I can't send the data I get from the selectlist to the controller. While doing this, I don't want to completely enclose the block I want to submit in the form tag. Can I just take the value of the element I want to send and keep it in the form tag?

I wrote a lot of javascript code to keep the value of the element I want to send and assign it to a variable, but I couldn't get any results.